# In an MDI Application, How can I have access to the Children

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I have a main form that can open MDI children inside it. so I open one child, then I open another child, now that I opended this second child I want to still be able to see what was the Top,Left of the first child so I can apply some resizing logic for the second child depending on that. So How I have access to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cycle through the MDI parent form's MdiChildren collection to find the open form(s) that you are interested in.